# understanding types

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell and I want to understand types. Assume that I have an object of type `Store`:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

type Variable = String

data Value = IntVal  Int
           | BoolVal Bool

type Store = Map Variable Value
```

How can use this object, say `s` to get value of variable?

And how to save value of a variable in `Store`?

Comment: Well, what did you try? Also, aliasing `String` to `Variable` seems confusing and silly.

Comment: Based on the wording of your question, I suspect you may be confusing types and values. By declaring `type Store = Map Variable Value` you have not created a map named "Store" in which to store things; you've only made a type alias. A value of type `Store` must be created using the available functions such as `empty`, `insert`, `fromList` from the `Data.Map` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some example usage:

```
s :: Store
s = fromList [("key1", IntVal 4), ("key2", BoolVal False)]

lookup "key1" s -- Just (IntVal 4)
lookup "key2" s -- Just (BoolVal False)
lookup "key3" s -- Nothing

s' :: Store
s' = insert "key3" (BoolVal True) s

lookup "key3" s' -- Just (BoolVal True)
```

Comment: on the second line I have `Not in scope fromList`. why?

Comment: @capoluca You need to import `Data.Map`. You'll also find that the `lookup` function from `Data.Map` clashes with a list-based function from `Prelude`, so I recommend doing `import Data.Map as M` and then using `M.lookup`.

Answer (score 3):

In a type declaration, the token on the left of the `=` is the type's name. Values to the right of the `=` define *constructors* - functions that create an instance of that type.

Consider the definition of Maybe, a simple type that represents the possibility of a failure (represented as `null` or `nil` in many languages):

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

This is a type with two constructors: `Just` and `Nothing`:

- The `Just` constructor represents success. It requires an argument of any type, representing the value to wrap
- The `Nothing` constructor takes no arguments. It represents failure.

You can see here that because `Maybe` has two constructors, there are two ways of constructing `Maybe` values. Such types are called *union* types. You extract values from union types using *pattern matching*. There are several language constructs that allow pattern matching (`let` and `where`-bindings, `case` statements, and function variable bindings). Below, we destructure a `Just` value in the arguments to a function.

```
fromJust :: Maybe a -> a
fromJust (Just x) = x
```

Assume this is loaded into GHCI. Here, we create an instance of `Maybe`, using the `Just` constructor, then retrieve that value again:

```
> let x = Just 20
> fromJust x

  20
```

Here's how pattern matching looks for your types. We create an instance of the `Store` type using the `Map` constructor you've defined:

```
> let m = Map "someVar" $ IntVal 0
```

Below we define a function that will extract the `Variable` value from a Map.

```
getVariable :: Store -> Variable
getVariable (Map v _) = v
```

Applying the function:

```
> getVariable m

  "someVar"
```

Hopefully the resources you're learning from will cover this stuff soon. If not, I recommend a dose of [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/).